# Wrong OAuth2 related configuration - Unity Google Play Service

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, leaderboard

Basically I was facing issue at the time of sign-up process. Here are two images to give you more idea about my problem:

1. Client Id Error

[image]

2. Wrong OAuth2

[image]

For this reason, I was getting failed during sign up time. If I upload new signed APK file within same game app then its get uploaded successfully so where exactly problem running that I can't able to understand.

What can I try next?

Comment: Deducing from your error 'web app client id is not associated with this game' you might be using the wrong Client ID. I think this [Unity3D forum](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1072780/unity-google-play-services-configuration-issues.html) will help address this issue.

Comment: Sorry but different discussion running over their :(